# MS Windows server 2008 installation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Im installing windows server 2008 on my Windows 7.

It seems like I will need to reinstall all programs after installing MS windows server 2008. I dont really want to do that, is there another way around it?

And how can i find out whether I already have Windows Server installed on my computer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two operating systems do not support an upgrade path.  You could do some unsupported things, IE exporting registry entries and importing them manually, but you're not likely to get things working the same way.  Further, some of your applications may not actually be supported on 2008.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979563(WS.10).aspx